# AmbiguousMatchException while match case property in OData

Tags: c#, odata

I have two properties with the same name and with a different case `Title` and `TITLE`:

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }

    public string TITLE { get; set; }
}
```

I'm including Title in OData config:

```
ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<Product>("Products");
        builder.EntityType<Product>().Property(a => a.Title);
        config.MapODataServiceRoute(
        routeName: "ODataRoute",
        routePrefix: null,
        model: builder.GetEdmModel());
```

Here is action of OData controller:

```
  public IHttpActionResult Get(ODataQueryOptions<Product> queryOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
     Context = GetContext();
     var products = Context.GetEntities<Product>();
     var result = queryOptions.ApplyTo(products);
     return Ok(result);
  }
```

When I send `https://localhost:44326/Products?$select=Id,TITLE` request, in `queryOptions.ApplyTo(products);` point I am getting following exception:

> System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException: 'Ambiguous match found.'

I want to get Title and TITLE property using $select. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Why do you have two properties that differ by case? Have you considered **not** doing that?

Comment: have you tried adding [DataMember(Name = "ProductTitle"] in your "Title" property?

Comment: @metal, I tried, but I'm still getting this exception

Comment: what's making it Ambiguous is the Title and TITLE

Comment: @metal, I understood this. In c# we can create the same properties with different cases. If there is no way to fix this problem, I will think about renaming these properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue of OData. This issue will be fixed in 7.3 version. Here is Pull request: 
https://github.com/OData/WebApi/pull/1907